# React native connect to laravel passport api and receive access token

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native

I set up the backend with Laravel and passport and everything goes correctly when I use postman but when I use `Axios` in `React native app` it gives me an error and doesn't load any response

**React code:**

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import {View , Text} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class Lapi extends Component {
    state = {
      url: 'http://laravelinstallation/api/user'
    };
    componentWillMount(){
        this.getUserInfo();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Test</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };
    getUserInfo(){
        axios.get(this.state.url)
            .then(response =>
                console.log(response.data)
    )
            .catch(err =>
                console.log(err)
            )
    }



}
export default Lapi;
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Failed to connect to rootcms.com/127.0.0.1:80

Answer (score 0):

Use your IP-address: `http://192.168.x.x/laravelinstallation/public/api/user`

You can get it by running ipconfig (Windows) or ifconfig (Mac/Linux)